# Auth.auth.currentUser.uid not working even though signIn worked

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app, when I first onboard users, I sign them in and I have confirmed that this works and they get a user ID. But later on in my storyboard, I am calling Auth.auth.currentUser.uid and this comes up as nil. At no point in my code am I signing out the User. This issue is super weird to me because of the fact that in most view controllers b4 the one that is crashing my app, currentUser.uid works fine, and I am able to store the users' data on Firebase. I have tried to debug and reached the conclusion that there is something about this viewcontroller code that makes this property nil. Has anyone encountered this issue b4? Here is some of my code for the view controller. *NOTE: for the variable DatabaseRef, I declare at the top of my class. I've read a bit about the concept of scope possibly being an issue here?

```
func getArrayOfMatches(){
    dataBaseRef=Database.database().reference()
    usedArray.removeAll()
    randomNumberArray.removeAll()
    finalPeopleArray.removeAll()
    peopleArray.removeAll()

    print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
    getUserGender()
    getUsersMatchPreferences()
    checkWhatPoolToDraw()
    getArray()


}

func getUsersMatchPreferences(){
    dataBaseRef=Database.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary=snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            self.userMatchPreferences=dictionary["AttractedTo"] as! String

        }

    }
}

func getArray(){
  dataBaseRef=Database.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("oldPotentialMatches").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let previousMatches=snapshot.value as? String
        if let oldPotential=previousMatches{
            self.usedArray.append(oldPotential)
        }
    }
    dataBaseRef.child(poolToDraw1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let personBook=snapshot.value as? String
        if (personBook != nil) && !self.usedArray.contains(personBook!){
            self.peopleArray.append(personBook!)
        }

    }
    getRandomizedNumbers()
    for i in 0...9{
        let randomNumber=randomNumberArray[i]
        let randomID=peopleArray[randomNumber]
        finalPeopleArray.append(randomID)
        usedArray.append(randomID)
    }
    for i in 0...usedArray.count-1{
       dataBaseRef.child("Users").child("")
    }
}
func getRandomizedNumbers(){
    var numIterations = 10
    if peopleArray.count < 10 {
        numIterations = peopleArray.count
    }
    for i in 0...numIterations{
        var randNumb = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(peopleArray.count)))
        while randomNumberArray.contains(randNumb){
            randNumb=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(peopleArray.count)))
        }
        randomNumberArray.append(randNumb)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% you are signed in to the point where the users UID can appear on the screen but you cannot do anything else then the most likely issue would be the Rulles for the Database, so you need to go to your firebase control panel click "Database" on the left hand menu and then "Rulles" on the Blue menu. For testing ONLY you can do this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: The sign in works but it’s just that when I get on this view controller I can’t access any of the data.

Comment: Because you are using an IOS it may be that you need to add a GoogleService-Info.plist file that you get from Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Answer (score 0):

Edit you config.xml to reference the GoogleService-Info.plist you need to do this for IOS when using Firebase, a work round would be to use the Firebase Web API that does not require this, but I dont know if that can be done with Swift.

Instructions to get it are here, you can put it into a folder

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

```
<platform name="ios">
...other stuff

        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" target="resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" />
```

and additional plugins example...

```
       <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
            <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
            <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" target="resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" />
        <config-file parent="NSMainNibFile" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string />
        </config-file>
<config-file parent="NSMainNibFile~ipad" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string />
</config-file>
 <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
 </feature>


</platform>
```